# What is the point of a function in a simple code [beginner Python]

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginning my journey through Python 3 and I'm learning about defining functions at the moment.

I have written 2 simple programs, one with a function, and one without. (see below). Can you please explain the usefulness (in this situation, and in general) of a function over no function? I'm guessing that using functions will save time in more advanced programs...

Thank you!

```
# Program with a function - Boolean test of user input in a list
def bird_available(bird):
     bird_types = 'crow robin parrot eagle sandpiper hawk pigeon'
     return bird.lower() in bird_types
bird_name = input("What bird are you looking for? ")
have_bird = bird_available(bird_name)
print(bird_name.capitalize(), "available is: ", have_bird)

# Simple Boolean test of user input in a list
bird_types = 'crow robin parrot eagle sandpiper hawk pigeon'
bird_name = input("What bird are you looking for? ")
print(bird_name.capitalize(), "available is: ", bird_name.lower() in bird_types)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular instance, there's effectively no difference. The point of functions is that you can reuse and maintain code much more easily. For example, if you were repeating this 10 times without functions and you wanted to add "raven" to the bird types, you'd have to add it to all 10 places where you defined the bird types. Having it in a function, you'd only have to change it once.